# eclipse and android sdk to Box.NET

Tags: android, eclipse, box-api

I was wondering if anyone has setup their development environment this way, or if there are any better alternatives. Since eclipse does not have to be "Installed" and can run from it's own folder it should be possible.

I want to save eclipse and the android sdk to my box.net account this way I can access my project and workspaces from any computer and they will all be synced up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) instead. I have seen people creating their workspaces in Dropbox folder. So that they can have their files where ever they want. Good thing about the Dropbox is it creates a folder in your system & it acts like just anyother folder in your system. I doubt if you can do it with box.net. So I would recommend to use Dropbox.  Hope this helps.

**Advantages**(summary)

1. Has associated installer for your platform. Creates a folder just like anyother folder inside your system & sending your app to cloud is just drag & drop
2. Free to use for 2GB space, same like box.net (Can be extended by referals)

Comment: I know I can do that But I was hoping to to more of a complete "Install" to the cloud. Have the android sdk and eclipse program be stored there so if i find myself on a new computer i can quickly grab everything and continue to develop. Obviously the computer would need java installed but past that do you see any issues?

Comment: Yes coz Android SDK uses the files dependent on Java JDK. & path & other libraries need not be of same filesystem version & also OS. Its always better to rebuild(clean build before run option in eclipse adb manager) your app based on your current system before you run. To ensure that there are no underlying glitches & foolproof.

Comment: Dropbox and only Dropbox will do what you want at this time.  It's way more expensive than competitors like Box who will give you 50gb just for signing up for a reason.  Box.net/com simply chokes on software projects. Too many metadata files and hidden files aren't synced. Dropbox has waded through the muck required to do this and the result is amazing, but you only realize this once you've tried every other solution.  It's far and away #1 for a reason.The only decision is whether this service is worth paying for (the cloud). If so,don't waste your time and install anything other than Dropbox.